# Is `assert_equal ... or assert_equal ...` possible in ruby minitest?

Tags: ruby, testing, minitest, assertions

I am creating a test that can be expressed as a disjunction of assertions; when the first assertion fails, then it should look at the next. Particularly, an item will be equal to one of two things. Which one, I do not know.

My code looks something like this. It does not work but it might give you an idea of what I am trying to do.

```
asset_one = Cache.asset_one
asset_two = Cache.asset_two

assert_equal(asset_one.name, Pages.name) or 
assert_equal(asset_two.name, Pages.name)
```

The `Pages.name` should match one of the targets. I don't know which one. If it doesn't match the first, then I want it to skip it and try to match the second.

Any help is as always much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to match any one of the object having the given name, you can use [assert_includes](https://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_125/MiniTest/Assertions/assert_includes)

```
asset_one = Cache.asset_one
asset_two = Cache.asset_two

assert_includes([asset_one, asset_two].map(&:name), Pages.name)
```

This should solve your purpose.